# Change onClick function for component react js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have component with button and 2 functions.Button component used in various components. And for some need one function for onclick event, for other - second. How can I change functions for onclick event? I'm using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36023138/3342929), but always getting undefined in my components.

```
export default class MyButtonComponent extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    propTypes: {
        onClick: PropTypes.func
    };
    this.state = { loading: false, api_url: "http://localhost:8000" };
}

 static get DefaultProps() {
  return {
    onClick: this.firstFunction(event)
  }
}

firstFunction(){
/*some code*/
}

secondFunction(){
/*some code*/
}

render() {
    return (
        <LaddaButton
            loading={this.state.loading}
            onClick={this.props.onClick}
            className='submit'
            data-color="#eee"
            data-style={SLIDE_UP}
            data-spinner-size={30}
            data-spinner-color="#ddd"
            data-spinner-lines={12}
            data-url={this.props.url}
        >
            Отправить
        </LaddaButton>

    );
}
```

And in another component:

```
<FormGroup>
     <Col mdOffset={5} md={7}>
         <MyButtonComponent onClick={this.secondFunction} data-url="someurl.com"></MyButtonComponent>
     </Col>
</FormGroup>
```

Also tried add

```
onClick={e => this.secondFunction(e)}
```

to button componentm but always getting error

```
_this2.secondFunction is not a function
```

Comment: is `secondFunction` defined in the parent component where the `<FormGroup>` is defined ?

Comment: no, form group from another component, secondfunction defined in button component.

Comment: `secondFunction` should not be defined in MyButtonComponent, it should be defined in the parent component

Comment: do you want to pass to button some kind of flag which specify what effect method from button should be fired or you want to pass method to be fired from parent?

Comment: second variant seems to be what I need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are passing `secondFunction()` as a prop to the `MyButtonComponent` component and hence it must not be defined in the `MyButtonComponent` component but in the component in which you have the below code

```
<FormGroup>
     <Col mdOffset={5} md={7}>
         <MyButtonComponent onClick={this.secondFunction} data-url="someurl.com"></MyButtonComponent>
     </Col>
</FormGroup>
```

In the `MyButtonComponent` you can reference it as `this.props.onClick()` but it must be defined in the calling component

Also you need to bind the function while passing it as a prop to the `MyButtonComponent` like

```
<FormGroup>
     <Col mdOffset={5} md={7}>
         <MyButtonComponent onClick={this.secondFunction.bind(this)} data-url="someurl.com"></MyButtonComponent>
     </Col>
</FormGroup>
```

Check the answer **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38394015/how-to-pass-data-from-child-component-to-its-parent-in-reactjs/38397755#38397755)** to understand the flow better

Comment: This is a much more elegant solution than mine - passing functions as properties of components is very flexible.

Answer (score 3):

The problem looks to be with how you're using `this` - when you call `this.secondFunction` in the `<FormGroup>` element of your other component, it's looking for `secondFunction` in *that* component. You've defined `secondFunction` in `MyButtonComponent`, so it's coming back as `undefined`.

You could get around this by defining a single click handler in `MyButtonComponent` that chooses which function to call based on a prop that you can update externally. E.g.

```
function myClickHandler(e) {
    if(useFirst) {
        this.firstFunction(e);
    } else {
        this.secondFunction(e);
    }
}
```

Then you could change that property in the render method of your other component, e.g.

```
<FormGroup>
    <Col mdOffset={5} md={7}>
        <MyButtonComponent useFirst=false data-url="someurl.com"></MyButtonComponent>
    </Col>
</FormGroup>
```